# EF7 Proxy Collections Not Generating

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying ASP.NET vNext / Entity Framework 7.

If I have 2 classes: A and B, where one A connects to many "B's," Entity Framework does not generate any proxy collection or proxy class. Thus, when trying to access the collection property, it is always empty unless I add to the collection manually. How does one implement lazy (or even eagerly) loaded collections in EF7?

```
public class A {
    public Guid UniqueId {get;set;}
    private ICollection<B> _backing;
    public virtual ICollection<B> OneToManyRelationship { 
      get { return _backing ?? (_backing = new Collection<B>()); }
      set { _backing = value; } }
}

public class B {
    public A Owner {get;set;}
    public string UniqueIdentifier {get;set;}
    public int SomeImportantData {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I know you're just playing around, but I believe right now everyone's direction is to continue using EF6 until EF7 becomes more robust. There are a lot of features that don't exist yet, that will in the (near) future.

Comment: @Mark C.: I wouldn't say it's *everyone's direction*.  Some classes of application can run today on EF 7 and stand to gain some real performance.  I'm moving our core app to EV 7 in the next few months.

Comment: @EricJ. I do agree with you that there are use cases. Everyone was definitely the wrong word to describe the populace here. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF 7 [does not support lazy loading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/27/ef7-v1-or-v7.aspx) upon initial release.

> An example of this is lazy loading support, we know this is a critical feature for a number of developers, but at the same time there are many applications that can be developed without this feature. Rather than making everyone wait until it is implemented, we will ship when we have a stable code base and are confident that we have the correct factoring in our core components. To be clear, it's not that we are planning to remove lazy loading support from EF7, just that some apps can start taking advantage of the benefits of EF7 before lazy loading is implemented.

Though I have not yet migrated to EF 7, you should be able to eagerly load your object graph, e.g.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

...

var query = ctx.A.Include(a => a.OneToManyRelationship);
```

Comment: Lazy loading is a colossal mistake which I've seen many architects disable out of the box because better to have a null result immediately obvious than to have death by a thousand cuts a few weeks later.

Comment: @JeffDunlop: Lazy loading can be the most efficient solution in some cases.  I don't see it as a mistake, but rather as an architectural option that needs to be properly understood.

Comment: Every instance of lazy load except for the one where nothing is loaded can be optimized -- without exception. You can take that to the bank and smoke it.

Comment: Optimized in terms of the time that a junior developer spends writing correct code with adequate performance?  Probably not.